# Nuget auto-checkout web.config(s)

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2015, nuget, resharper

During the installation (or restore) of a Nuget package, it also checkout web.config(s) of other projects and I manually have to go one by one to undo all of this unnecessary checkouts.
How to avoid this?

Comment: I've noticed this too.

Comment: Could you reproduce this issue stably? Or is  this just a probability  problem? I can't reproduce your problem with a new created empty web application.

Comment: Which package did you install?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are using a **Server Workspace** (*a workspace configured for Server mode*)

As a workaround you could change to a [**Local Workspace**](https://www.visualstudio.com/da-dk/docs/tfvc/decide-between-using-local-server-workspace#why-should-i-use-a-local-workspace). In a local workspace files are not marked as read only and can be edited outside of Visual Studio.